# Why is this form invalid?

Tags: python, django

the models.py contains 2 classes, class ageGen() and class group1(),which works fine .

**forms.py**

```
from app1.models import ageGen,group1,group2,group3
from django import forms

class ageGenForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model=ageGen
        fields='__all__'

class group1form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model=group1
        fields="__all__"
```

what I am trying to do is .. the ageGenForm will accept the age and gender of the player and then it will check weather the player is above 18 years old . 
if he is below 18 years , then he has to fill up a form specifying his name and the games he wants to participate in and this data is stored in the database .

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from app1.forms import ageGenForm,group1form,group2form,group3form
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')

def formpage(request):
    form=ageGenForm()
    if(request.method=='POST'):
        form=ageGenForm(request.POST)
        if(form.is_valid()):
            age = form.cleaned_data['age']
            if(age<=18):
                return group1(request)
            else:
                return HttpResponse("adult category")
    return render(request,'formpage.html',{'form':form})

def group1(request):
    form=group1form()
    if(request.method=='POST'):
        form=group1form(request.POST)
        if(form.is_valid()):
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse("thankyou!")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("invalid")
    return render(request,'group1.html',{'form':form})
```

it renders the formpage.html but doesnt render the group1.html . It returns form invalid ! and it doesn't shoot any error .

formpage.html and group1.html **(same code for both)**:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>formpage</h1>
        <form method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{form.as_p}}
          <input type="submit" name="" value="SUBMIT">
        </form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting on the console? Or try to use return redirect('YOUR_NAME_FIELD_FROM_URL') instead of  return group1(request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly call a view from another view. Instead, you need to call its url. Suppose you have an [URL path](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#path) like this:

```
path('group1/', views.group1, name="group1")
```

Then from `formpage`, you can [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) to that URL path on form valid, like this(using [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)):

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse


def formpage(request):
    form=ageGenForm()
    if(request.method=='POST'):
        form=ageGenForm(request.POST)
        if(form.is_valid()):
            age = form.cleaned_data['age']
            if(age<=18):
                return redirect(reverse('group1'))  #<-- Redirecting to group1 view
            else:
                return HttpResponse("adult category")
    return render(request,'formpage.html',{'form':form})
```